# Error installing WCF Data Service Client for Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-store-apps, wcf-data-services-client

I am working with Windows Store apps. I have backend with WCF Data Services. When I try to add service I have error which says I need to install WCF Data Services Client and put link to 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj658961.

After I downloaded, when I try to install it, I have an error:
0x800b0101 - A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp in the signed file.

I provide the log section that comes with error:

`[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to verify certificate chain policy status.

[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to get certificate chain for authenticode certificate.

[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to verify signature of payload: wcf_dataservices

[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Failed to verify payload: wcf_dataservices at path: D:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\wcf_dataservices, error: 0x800b0101. Deleting file.

[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to cache payload: wcf_dataservices

[2094:1F08][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Failed to cache payload: wcf_dataservices from working path: D:\Users\TMACON~1.BAL\AppData\Local\Temp{1dff3448-2deb-42be-a710-36bfc79c5d5c}\wcf_dataservices, error: 0x800b0101.

[2094:1F08][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Application requested retry of payload: wcf_dataservices, encountered error: 0x800b0101. Retrying...

[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to verify certificate chain policy status.

[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to get certificate chain for authenticode certificate.

[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to verify signature of payload: wcf_dataservices

[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Failed to verify payload: wcf_dataservices at path: D:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\wcf_dataservices, error: 0x800b0101. Deleting file.

[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to cache payload: wcf_dataservices

[2094:1F08][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Failed to cache payload: wcf_dataservices from working path: D:\Users\TMACON~1.BAL\AppData\Local\Temp{1dff3448-2deb-42be-a710-36bfc79c5d5c}\wcf_dataservices, error: 0x800b0101.

[2094:1F08][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Application requested retry of payload: wcf_dataservices, encountered error: 0x800b0101. Retrying...

[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to verify certificate chain policy status.

[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to get certificate chain for authenticode certificate.

[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to verify signature of payload: wcf_dataservices

[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Failed to verify payload: wcf_dataservices at path: D:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\wcf_dataservices, error: 0x800b0101. Deleting file.

[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to cache payload: wcf_dataservices

[2094:1F08][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Failed to cache payload: wcf_dataservices from working path: D:\Users\TMACON~1.BAL\AppData\Local\Temp{1dff3448-2deb-42be-a710-36bfc79c5d5c}\wcf_dataservices, error: 0x800b0101.

[2094:0708][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed while caching, aborting execution.`

Could someone explain, what certificate is needed and how could I solve my problem with this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved issue by updating WCF Data Services to version 5.6.0. After that I was able to use my WCF Data Service.

Comment: This can be accessed by using NuGet to add the reference.