# Error installing WCF Data Service Client for Windows Store Apps version 2

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I am working with Windows Store apps. I have backend with WCF Data Services. When I try to add service I have error which says I need to install WCF Data Services Client and put link to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj658961.

After I downloaded, when I try to install it, I have an error: 0x800b0101 - A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp in the signed file.

I provide the log section that comes with error:

```
    [2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to verify certificate chain              policy status.
[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to get certificate chain for authenticode certificate.
[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to verify signature of payload: wcf_dataservices
[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Failed to verify payload: wcf_dataservices at path: D:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\wcf_dataservices, error: 0x800b0101. Deleting file.
[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to cache payload: wcf_dataservices
[2094:1F08][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Failed to cache payload: wcf_dataservices from working path: D:\Users\TMACON~1.BAL\AppData\Local\Temp{1dff3448-2deb-42be-a710-36bfc79c5d5c}\wcf_dataservices, error: 0x800b0101.
[2094:1F08][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Application requested retry of payload: wcf_dataservices, encountered error: 0x800b0101. Retrying...
[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to verify certificate chain policy status.
[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to get certificate chain for authenticode certificate.
[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to verify signature of payload: wcf_dataservices
[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Failed to verify payload: wcf_dataservices at path: D:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\wcf_dataservices, error: 0x800b0101. Deleting file.
[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to cache payload: wcf_dataservices
[2094:1F08][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Failed to cache payload: wcf_dataservices from working path: D:\Users\TMACON~1.BAL\AppData\Local\Temp{1dff3448-2deb-42be-a710-36bfc79c5d5c}\wcf_dataservices, error: 0x800b0101.
[2094:1F08][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Application requested retry of payload: wcf_dataservices, encountered error: 0x800b0101. Retrying...
[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to verify certificate chain policy status.
[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to get certificate chain for authenticode certificate.
[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to verify signature of payload: wcf_dataservices
[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Failed to verify payload: wcf_dataservices at path: D:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\wcf_dataservices, error: 0x800b0101. Deleting file.
[2EBC:16AC][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed to cache payload: wcf_dataservices
[2094:1F08][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Failed to cache payload: wcf_dataservices from working path: D:\Users\TMACON~1.BAL\AppData\Local\Temp{1dff3448-2deb-42be-a710-36bfc79c5d5c}\wcf_dataservices, error: 0x800b0101.
[2094:0708][2013-10-11T11:52:07]: Error 0x800b0101: Failed while caching, aborting execution.
```

Could someone explain, what certificate is needed and how could I solve my problem with this error?

I'm just copying someone else's post to a new thread since I don't have enough reputation even to post a comment sadly...
Tomas -> https://stackoverflow.com/users/2853943/tomas
posted an answer here -> [Error installing WCF Data Service Client for Windows Store Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19321131/error-installing-wcf-data-service-client-for-windows-store-apps) and I had actually figured that out one day earlier and I could successfully add the reference service however when I try to compile it it throws me errors and it cant find mostly the System.Data namespace..any clue why this is happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

nevermind on this post i guess, i added the dll reference assenblies from here -> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft WCF Data Services\5.6\bin\tools) to the project and so far it seems to be working, havent finished the project yet but lets see if no further errors is thrown again..
any news i will post back here